# How to ensure that Gson's output in toJson() is ASCII?

Tags: java, python, json, ascii, gson

Is there are a setting that can be enabled in Gson, that can ensure that the JSON output received is always ASCII encoded, regardless of whether UTF8 strings were present in the input?

In languages like Python, this is easily done, because the default setting in the standard Python JSON library has ensure_ascii=True:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = u"Â™"
>>> json.dumps(a)
'"\\u00c2\\u2122"'
>>> json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=True)
'"\\u00c2\\u2122"'
>>> json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False)
u'"\xc2\u2122"'
```

Gson does not seem to escape all unicode characters with "\uxxxx". Is there a setting to replicate Python like behaviour?

Comment: [Relevant source](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson does not have any support for this (there is no requirement for JSON to be encoded in ASCII).

Just post-process the json to manually substitute the correct escape sequences.